# Why tesseract is not recognising text from this image?

Tags: python, image, text, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to get the text from these images. When I run the code is below, in the first picture recognize "Legendary x" but the second picture doesnt recognize anything. I dont undertand what is wrong

```
def get_text(image, coord):
   im = Image.open(image)
   image_cropped = crop_text(im, coord)
   text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image_cropped, config='--psm 6')
   return text.replace('\n', '').replace('\f', '')
```

[First picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezIJG.png)
[Second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGlZs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the tesseract docs:
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/main/ImproveQuality.md

Comment: Thank you so much! I just change the image to black and white and the it works